# Set keep-alive for WebHttpBinding programmatically

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm wondering how to disable keepAlive for webHttpBinding. I know I can do it this way:

```
<bindings>
<customBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpWithoutKeepAlive">
        <webMessageEncoding />
        <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
<service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
<endpoint address="http://localhost:9005/"
      binding="customBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WebHttpWithoutKeepAlive"
      contract="IMyService"
      behaviorConfiguration="myServerEndpointBehavior"/>
</service>
</services>
```

How can I do that same thing programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Binding CreateBinding()
{
    Binding binding = new WebHttpBinding();

    CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);
    var transportElement = customBinding.Elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>();
    transportElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;

    return customBinding;
}
```